# Stubbing write method inside File.open using Mocha in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-mocha

My spec_helper.rb has the following configuration:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.mock_with :mocha
    # .. other configs
end
```

I want to test the following piece of code:

```
File.open('filename.zip', 'wb') do |file|
    file.write('some file content')
end
```

So here is my spec:

```
file_handle = mock
file_handle.stubs(:write).with('some file content').once
File.stubs(:open).with('filename.zip', 'wb').returns(file_handle).once
```

But the output says there is no invocation of `write` method.

Here is the output:

```
MiniTest::Assertion: not all expectations were satisfied
unsatisfied expectations:
- expected exactly once, not yet invoked: #<Mock:0x7fdcdde109a8>.write('some file content')
satisfied expectations:
- expected exactly once, invoked once: File.open('filename.zip', 'wb')
```

So am I stubbing the `write` method in the right way? If not, is there any other way to write spec for method invocation inside `do |obj| ..end` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply write:

```
file_handle = mock
file_handle.stubs(:write).with('some file content').once
File.stubs(:open).with('filename.zip', 'wb').yields(file_handle).once
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice your answer first.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure it is your case but I think it can help you

I needed to change behavior inside block `File.open(...) do ... end`

I managed to do it this way

```
origin_open = File.method(:open)
allow(File).to receive(:open) do |*args, &block|
  if condition
    # change behavior here
    # for example change args
  end
  # call original method with modified args
  origin_open.call(*args, &block)
end
```

This [article](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-1/docs/configuring-responses/block-implementation) helped me a lot